# Google OAuth2, how to use remember me to prevent having to re-login?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I've just implemented a OAuth2 login in on my application through Google. Although, being that this is an entirely new thing to me, I have no idea how the sessions will function now.

Previously, with my old login system. The session would last for 5 minutes before expiring. But I had a remember-me token that would prevent having to re-login. With OAuth2, I don't see any remember-me token even though I've got it enabled. I only see my JSESSION cookie. So when my session expires, I'm forced to log back in.

I'm using Sping boot, along with Spring Security, and Spring OAuth2. Hosting it all on Tomcat 8 (Which is managing the sessions).

So how would I prevent a user from having to constantly log back in?

Comment: You can use a [refresh token](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html#oauth2Client-refresh-token-grant) to automatically refresh the client access token.

Comment: I've got a refresh token system. The issue is when the HTTP session expires from Tomcat, it will not be resumed. Whereas with a normal login system, I use a remember-me token to re-login the user but apparently OAuth2 on Spring doesn't support remember-me tokens